# Is it a good practice to keep a Socket connection open for reading?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to build an Android IM, since users may have new messages from others, should I keeps the TCP connection open and keep reading data from it? e.g.

```
while(!shutdown) {
    int count = socketChannel.read(buffer);
    // do something with buffer
}
```

Comment: Unclear how *else* you could receive those messages.

Comment: @EJP, You are surprisingly active on the site, thanks so much. Is it better that I `Thread.sleep` for a while (e.g. 100ms)  if I don't get any data from the socket ? Will this save some CPU ?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your implementation. If you're using blocked sockets then you wouldn't want to do this. It would mean that if you have more than one client connecting to the server they would block all other clients from connecting to that server socket.
What you could do is have a server socket running consistently (as you normally would) and then to connect to it with a client socket to check and receive any new messages that have arrived. Once you've received your message you can close the socket. This could be performed every n seconds.
The other option is to use non-blocked socket connections and always keep them open but this could lead to issues if you have many clients.